# Is there a max size, max no. of columns, max rows?

Tags: python, pandas

.. and, if so, what are those max limits of pandas?

Sorry, this question seems elementary but I couldn't find an answer at pandas.pydata.org.

Answer (score 40):

The **limit is your memory**. ( but these limits are really large )

On the other hand, concerning the possibility of displaying a large number of rows or columns, for example in "Jupyter Notebook", there is some predefined limits.

For example you can:

```
print (pd.options.display.max_columns) # <--- this will display your limit
pd.options.display.max_columns = 500 # this will set limit of columns to 500
```

The same idea work with rows:

```
display.max_rows
```

More details on:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html

Answer (score 34):

No. `Pandas` uses numpy arrays under the hood, so I belive it's whatever you can fit in your memory. As far as numpy arrays are concerned, you can find some discussion [here](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/numpy-discussion@python.org/thread/IWXTJZYD2EBSL7H5GGP7XNDAIYLBYREW/).

Answer (score -1):

You can do that easily with `.set_option()` function.

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500) 
# Where 500 is the maximum number of rows that you want to show
```

Comment: Misleading answer. The question is not related to display.