# How to iteratively append a dataframe representing a spatial x and y scenario using nested for loops?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a dataframe to represent a topographical expression. So far I've written a pair of for loops that can individually be used to express the x and y axis, specifically in the forms,

```
a = []   
for x in range(1,i,1):
    x1 = some function of x
    x2 = another function of x 
    a.append({'a':x, 'b':x1, 'c': x2})
xaxis = pd.DataFrame(a)
```

for the x axis and,

```
a = []
for y in range(-j, j, 1):
    y1 = some function of y   
    a.append({'a':y,'b':y1})
yaxis = pd.DataFrame(a)
```

for the y axis.

That's all simple enough and works fine, however...

I want to expand on this such that the y axis loop is repeated with each iteration of the x axis loop and have the y1 function depend on the parameters of the x axis loop. I get this far,

```
a = []   
for x in range(1,i,1):
    x1 = some function of x
    x2 = another function of x 
    for y in range(-j, j, 1):
        y1 = some function of y that calls x2
    a.append({
```

and I'm stumped.

The output I'm after is essentially this,

```
x    x1      x2     y    y1       
     x1(1)   x2(1)  -j   y1(1,-j)  
1    x1(1)   x2(1)  0    y1(1,0)   
     x1(1)   x2(1)  j    y1(1,j)      
     x1(2)   x2(2)  -j   y1(2,-j)  
2    x1(2)   x2(2)  0    y1(2,0)   
     x1(2)   x2(2)  j    y1(2,j)  
....
```

and so on to x = i.

The end desire is to have data that can be plotted in a 2D histogram

If there's a better way to do this then please do let me know, this is just the only way I can currently think of that may get the result I'm after.

edit: Turns out this can be done quite effectively using numpy arrays. This is a general expression on how I achieved this goal in the end,

```
y1 = lambda x,y: f(x,y)
np.array( [ [ y1(x,y) for x in xrange(1,i,1)] for y in xrange(-j,j,1)] )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find a vectorized version of your functions. This can be achieved (for intstant) by using `numpy`'s several vectorized functions or by using `numpy.vectorized()`. Take a look on that example :

```
import numpy as np

def f1(x):
    return x**2

def f2(x):
    return np.abs(x)

def f3(x,y):
    return x**2 + y**2

i = 3 ; j = 2
x = np.arange(1,i,1)
y = np.arange(-j,j,1)

# Now build cartesian product of x and y
xy = np.array([np.tile(x, len(y)), np.repeat(y, len(x))])
xy
array([[ 1,  2,  1,  2,  1,  2,  1,  2],
       [-2, -2, -1, -1,  0,  0,  1,  1]])

x1 = f1(xy[0,])
x1
array([1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4], dtype=int32)

x2 = f2(xy[0,])
x2
array([1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2])

y1 = f3(xy[0,], xy[1,])
y1
array([5, 8, 2, 5, 1, 4, 2, 5], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! The functions are just equations, here they are:         
x1 = np.exp(-1.55*x) + 1.2*np.exp(-1.27629*x ** (1.0/2)) + 0.96*np.exp(-2.07668*x ** (1.0/3))                   
x2 = 98.508*x ** 0.961              
y1 = x1*2e6*np.exp(((-y ** 2)/(x2 ** 2))/2)

Comment: As an FYI, I've had a little bit of success towards what I'm trying to do using groupby, however I'm running into memory usage issues well before completion. This dataframe I'm aiming for is going to have 400 million rows, which seems to be too much for pandas.

Comment: Since your functions are just combination of numpy functions, they're already vectorized and the above solution must work (don't forget to adapt variable names and format). For your memory issues, technically [Pandas has no limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455722/pandas-is-there-a-max-size-max-no-of-columns-max-rows) and only your hard-drive will limit you. If necessary, please open another question since asking many and many questions under the same post is not recommanded.

Comment: Alrighty, I did wonder if it was the case that things were already vectorized but now I know. Thanks for the help :) I'll give this a crack on a better machine and see how it goes.

Comment: Hi again, this isn't quite what I was after. Let's say I enter a range of (1, 11, 1) for x and (-5,5,1) for y I end up with a series 10 values long for y1 whereas I'm looking for all 100 points that would be in the 10 x 10 matrix

Comment: I have edited the proposed solution. Test it and give a feedback

Comment: Hey man, thanks again for the suggestion. It's not quite what I'm after but you pointed me in the right direction and after a lot of trial and error I figured out how to get what I was after. I'll put up my solution.