# Using Pandas in Python on datasets too large for excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, sas

I had a quick application question on using pandas in python to analyze large excel sheets.

For data that have millions of rows (beyond Excel's limit), how can we deal with analyzing them through pandas?

I know excel lets you load data from a text file and have your excel spreadsheet "create a connection" to the source file without having to load all the millions of rows directly. If we call this excel spreadsheet using pandas in python, will we be able to use our filter operations (and all the other table data analysis operations we've learned ) on all the millions of rows from the source file? Or will it just execute on only what shows up on the excel sheet (assuming we have selected the "create a connection" option to the source text file )?

Is there a more efficient way of using pandas with sas files directly?

Comment: You can do almost anything you want with pandas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas: Is there a max size, max no. of columns, max rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455722/pandas-is-there-a-max-size-max-no-of-columns-max-rows)

Answer (score 0):

I think getting files via small chunks can make the process efficient. Please look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622652/large-persistent-dataframe-in-pandas/12193309#12193309)