# Fetching data from postgres database on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm having this script to fetch data from Postgres DB.

```
POSTGRES_PORT = 'xxxx'
POSTGRES_USERNAME = 'xxx' ## CHANGE THIS TO YOUR PANOPLY/POSTGRES USERNAME
POSTGRES_PASSWORD = 'xxx' ## CHANGE THIS TO YOUR PANOPLY/POSTGRES PASSWORD POSTGRES_DBNAME = 'xxxx' ## CHANGE THIS TO YOUR DATABASE NAME
POSTGRES_DBNAME = 'xxx'

postgres_str = (f'postgresql://{POSTGRES_USERNAME}:{POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@{POSTGRES_ADDRESS}:{POSTGRES_PORT}/{POSTGRES_DBNAME}')
# Create the connection
cnx = create_engine(postgres_str)
```

When I use the limit, I'm able to fetch it.

```
table_name = pd.read_sql_query("""SELECT * FROM public.timeline limit 1000""", cnx)
table_name
```

When I try to fetch without limit, I got this error

**"Connection failed
A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration."**

In this case, would you recommend I use pyspark? As it looks the data is bigdata?

I use the count and I got "66231781" rows.

Comment: It would be good to paste exactly what error stops you from fetching the results. For now I can only guess the limit is your [memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15455722/5298879). In that case, if you try to pull the entire table with all of its columns at once, into one object, I'd expect this to be problematic no matter what tool you use.

Comment: Hello @Zegarek, just added my error message

Comment: If you could paste the error as text, it'll be searchable by other users with the same problem. The error is likely caused by a timeout when the notebook's busy loading the data - you can consider increasing [one of the time limits](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html). I agree with the answer suggesting you should consider pagination because even if you let it load longer, you might still be unable to fit it in your memory or work with the data effectively. You can ask the db about table size with `select pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('public.timeline'));`

Comment: Hello @Zegarek, thanks for the feedback, already pasted the error and I'll try out the things you mentioned. thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the database driver for Postgresql uses a client side cursor, but you can use a server side cursor and stream the data to the client in batches. The following code will iterate through the query result in batches of 1,000 rows as set by the `chunksize` parameter. You can adjust the value of `chunksize` to meet your needs.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(f"postgresql://{POSTGRES_USERNAME}:{POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@{POSTGRES_ADDRESS}:{POSTGRES_PORT}/{POSTGRES_DBNAME}")

with engine.connect().execution_options(stream_results=True) as conn:
    for chunk_df in pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM public.timeline", conn, chunksize=1000):
        print(f"Dataframe has {len(chunk_df)} rows.")
```

Comment: Hello @Dan, thanks for your comment, but I think due to the size of the data, I always lost the connection while trying to run. Do you think that to use Pyspark could help?

Comment: If your intention is to execute queries such as `SELECT * FROM public.timeline` which you have said returns millions of records then Spark is not going to help because the results will still need to be returned to the client.